# ReferenceError: m is not defined react build runtime errors

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl

I am getting runtime errors on a react build which otherwise works perfectly with yarn start. I read two consecutive "Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined" on the chrome console. The major dependencies of the app are deck.gl, mapbox, and material-ui. Node version v14.15.5 and npm version 6.14.11. I suspect it has to do with the bundling process. Let me know what else i can provide to troubleshoot this problem.

list of project dependencies for reference:

```
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.16",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.10.8",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@deck.gl/core": "^8.4.6",
    "@deck.gl/geo-layers": "^8.4.6",
    "@deck.gl/layers": "^8.4.6",
    "@deck.gl/mesh-layers": "^8.4.6",
    "@deck.gl/react": "^8.4.6",
    "@loaders.gl/i3s": "^2.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "d3-scale": "^3.2.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.1.4",
    "react-native-rheostat": "^0.1.0"
```

Comment: Do you use materialize ?

Comment: No, Ill update my post to list out the dependencies

Comment: Any solution for this? Same issue. I use react-map-gl and deck gl too.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, see this long thread: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10173. I fixed the problem by using the CRACO method described there

Answer (score 1):

this is an issue related to `mapbox v2` as mentioned [in this long thread](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10173). I also had a similar issue with my `React`, `DeckGL` project and after downgrading to `react-map-gl` to version `^5.3.17`, the problem has been solved.

This is just a workaround for this particular issue until the Mapbox team comes up with a better fix.